# Conceptual Class Diagram

Tags: uml

I am trying to draw a conceptual class diagram. In my system, I have one person who can be performing 2 roles. One being "teacher" and other being "student". The same person could be a teacher in one instance and the same person could be a student in another instance. In such a situation, is it good to depict them as 2 separate classes (in my conceptual diagram)?

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the person is teaching themself, don't get caught up in trying to show relationships that cross a use-case boundary.  Validate the links for each scenario separately; just realize that not all connections will be used for every scenario.

People fill roles.  Try

Person associated with EducationRole

EducationRole has subclasses of 'Student' and 'Teacher'

Here is a diagram.

[image: diagram]

They can change the role they play depending on the situation.  If you need to show a person teaching themself then create a subclass of EducationRole named 'Autodiadact' which just means self-teacher.

A commenter asked about changing the role using a method and I'd like to include the answer here.

So, yes you could code the ability to change the role in a method but back up and ask the bigger question, why are we changing the role?  A teacher is becoming a student or a student is becoming a teacher, either way the model as shown allows a Person to have many EducationRoles (which is what the asterisk denotes) at the same time so there isn't really a need to change the role but support a person with multiple possible roles.

In the conceptual model you are attempting to illustrate relationships between any valid state of the system, not necessarily how the change might be executed (using a method).

Comment: +1  This the 'party-role' pattern, quite a common situation. There are variants, e.g. if the number of roles isn't fixed at run time.  Some googling for "Party-Role Pattern" will help.

Comment: Thanks folks. I got the hang of it now.

Comment: Can we modify a role by using a method (setEducationRole() ?) How do we do that ?